# Extended maxima transform in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I use `imtophat` to apply a filter to an `m x n` array. I then find the local max using `imextendedmax()`. I get mostly 0's everywhere except for 1's in the general areas where I am expecting a local max. The weird thing is, though, that I don't get just one local max. Instead in these places I get MANY elements with 1's such as

```
00011100000 
00111111000 
00000110000
```

yet the values there are close but NOT equal so I would expect that there would be one that is higher than all of the rest. So I'm wondering:

1. if this is a bug and how I might fix it
2. how you would choose choose the element of these 1's with the highest value.

Answer (score 4):

a) This is a feature. You are calling `imextendedmax` with two input arguments. The second input is a measure for how different pixels can be from the maximum and still be counted for the extended maximum.

b) You can choose the elements with the highest value using `max` on the pixels within the group.

```
%# for testing, create a  mask with two groups and an image of corresponding size
msk = repmat([00011100000;...
00111111000;...
00000110000],1,2);

img = rand(size(msk));
imSize = size(img);

%# to find groups of connected ones, apply connected component labeling
cc = bwconncomp(msk);

%# loop through all groups and find the location of the maximum intensity pixel
%# You could do this without loop, but it would be much less readable
maxCoordList = zeros(cc.NumObjects,2);
for i = 1:cc.numObjects
    %# read intensities corresponding to group
     int = img(cc.PixelIdxList{i});

    %# find which pixel is brightest
    [maxInt,maxIdx] = max(int);

    %# maxIdx indexes into PixelIdxList, which indexes into the image.
    %# convert to [x,y]
    maxCoordList = ind2sub(imSize,cc.PixelIdxList{i}(maxIdx));
end

%# confirm by plotting
figure
imshow(img,[])
hold on
plot(maxCoordList(:,2),maxCoordList(:,1),'.r')
```